# kubectl command cannot find namespace value

Tags: google-app-engine, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy an application vis Google Cloud with K8. I ran `kubectl create -f app.yaml` and everything seemed to work fine. I can go to my Project profile and view the "app" cluster in the "Kubernetes clusters"  page. However, when I try to view my pods and their info via the terminal I run into this strange situation:

```
% kubectl get pods -n app
No resources found in app namespace.

% kubectl create -f app.yaml 
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "app.yaml": services "app" already exists

% kubectl -n app rollout restart deployment project
Error from server (NotFound): namespaces "app" not found
```

kubectl cannot find the name "app" but I cannot recreate "app" because the name already exists!

My end goal is to view the pods info and get the External IP value.

Comment: Can you share the contents of `app.yaml`? That would probably make it easier to understand what's causing your kubectl commands to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My end goal is to view the pods info and get the External IP value:

- To get info about pods, try `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide`
  Right now there are just no pods in namespace app according to this error "No resources found in app namespace."
  Running the above will give you more info.
- `kubectl get svc -o wide`
  should provide you with the external IP you are looking for.